# Is there such a thing as the philosophy of romance?

Tags: reference-request, love

Is there such a thing as the philosophy of romance and romantic attraction? I understand that there are philosophies behind quite a lot of things, so I would not be surprised if there was such a thing as the philosophy of romance. If there is, I would like to read texts about it.

Comment: Why are you Asking that here, instead of through your search engine of choice? 

To me, it seems that what justifies Posting here, is what your engine failed at…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Romance is subsidiary to the concept of love. To introductory articles are:

- [Philosophy of Love (IEP)](https://iep.utm.edu/love/)
- [Love (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/love/)

The IEP has a short subsection devoted to the concept:

> Romantic love is deemed to be of a higher metaphysical and ethical status than sexual or physical attractiveness alone. The idea of romantic love initially stems from the Platonic tradition that love is a desire for beauty-a value that transcends the particularities of the physical body. For Plato, the love of beauty culminates in the love of philosophy, the subject that pursues the highest capacity of thinking. The romantic love of knights and damsels emerged in the early medieval ages (11th Century France, fine amour) a philosophical echo of both Platonic and Aristotelian love and literally a derivative of the Roman poet, Ovid and his Ars Amatoria. Romantic love theoretically was not to be consummated, for such love was transcendentally motivated by a deep respect for the lady; however, it was to be actively pursued in chivalric deeds rather than contemplated-which is in contrast to Ovid’s persistent sensual pursuit of conquests!

You can also look at the [PhilPapers.org search results for 'philosophy of love'](https://philpapers.org/s/philosophy%20of%20love).